# ValueError in creating submission csv

Tags: csv, pandas, kaggle, sklearn-pandas

I am learning data science and reading other people's scripts. There is this one titanic algorithm (kaggle) has this code to apply the Logistic Regression then supposedly export to a .csv file as suggested in the code. However, it always generates an error message after I run the code. The original script is found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/wikaiqi/titanic/titaniclearningqi), and the .csv data that's being read into the code is here: [train.csv](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/download/train.csv) [test.csv](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/download/test.csv)

From Input[24] to Input[28] are for setting up LogisticRegression. Up to Input[27] the code still runs without error. When running Input[28]:

```
    acc_log = predict_model(X_data, Y_data, logreg, X_test_kaggle, 'submission_Logistic.csv')
```

I receive an error message:

```
    ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Q'
```

I tried to add "try/except" to bypass the error message so the code can continue.

```
    try:
        acc_log = predict_model(X_data, Y_data, logreg, X_test_kaggle, 'submission_Logistic.csv')
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

This code is a bit too sophisticated for me to debug to see which step goes wrong and where in the file that has the string in place of the desired input for a float. So I would like to ask for help here to better understand this and seek for a proper solution. Thanks.

Comment: Please post a snippet of both the data set and the predict_model() function, without those, it's nearly impossible to tell.  But clearly you're passing a string into a function that is expecting a float.

Comment: Hi @pshep123 thank you for your input. I have edited the question and added in references. I am not sure which section of the code and data set I should copy and paste, so I listed the references here instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you didn't run cell 16 in the notebook link you provided, in which `Embarked` values are converted to integers (including the string value `Q`, which is throwing the error you're seeing):

**Cell 16**

```
# fill the missing values of Embarked feature with the most common occurance
freq_port = train_df.Embarked.dropna().mode()[0]
for dataset in combine:
    dataset['Embarked'] = dataset['Embarked'].fillna(freq_port)
train_df[['Embarked', 'Survived']].groupby(['Embarked'], as_index=False).mean().sort_values(by='Survived', ascending=False)

for dataset in combine:
    dataset['Embarked'] = dataset['Embarked'].map( {'S': 0, 'C': 1, 'Q': 2} ).astype(int)

train_df.head()
```

I just ran all the cells in order and the `LogisticRegression` section worked fine for me.  Try shutting down your notebook and re-running all the cells in the order they appear.

A general data science tip:
When you've already trained a model but your `predict()` function is throwing an error, it's helpful to look at the test data you're inputting and try and figure out what's wrong there.
In this case, searching the values in `X_test_kaggle` for the string `Q` might have revealed the problem was with the `Embarked` field, and that could have served as a first breadcrumb in tracking the problem back to its source.

Comment: Thanks @andrew_reece! I checked the code and my input was missing a line from this section. I tried to type things by hand so that did slip without noticing it. Good catch and thanks for sharing with me your experience too :)